Why wouldn't an infinite past of exhaustive events have already lead to the end of the world?
I.e., If everything happens in an infinite time period, then if there were an infinite time up until now, then why hasn't the world ended yet? Isn't the ending of the world one of the kinds of things that could, and here would, happen?
The idea that "in an infinite time, everything happens" is hard to source and this Quora thread includes some decent testimony against the claim.
Still, if the claim is accepted as a premise for the sake of argument, then why hasn't the world ended yet?

"I'm sorry, daniel, I don't understand the question."

Some Christian philosophers, like William Lane Craig, would answer by saying that an actually infinite set of past events, one after the other, leads to absurdities; and thus, would argue that the universe must have had a beginning, and by extension, an adequate Cause (God).  Craig has a video which discusses the topic philosophically, specifically about the impossibility of an infinity of past events.  I've summarized his argument in this answer.
